# Flutter - How to set dynamic base url in Retrofit API request?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

Here is the example of my post API and I want to change the base URL for this particular API endpoint.

```
@POST("/post")
@FormUrlEncoded()
Future<String> postUrlEncodedFormData(@Field() String hello);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some resource I got this solution and its work for me.

```
@POST("http://www.your_base_url.com/post")
@FormUrlEncoded()
Future<String> postUrlEncodedFormData(@Field() String hello);
```